# How to match values from a data frame to another

Tags: r, sequence, fasta

I downloaded 876 DNA sequences of a 276 nucleotides length and made a df with the information.
`TOTAL <- read.csv("TOTAL.csv")
TOTAL
Ind   Seq                              Tipo
1     AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTC...   _NA_
2     AACTTTTAAAAACGGGTTCTTTGGTTC...   _NA_
3     AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTC...   _NA_
4     AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTC...   _NA_
52    AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGGTC...   _NA_
821   AACTTTCAACAACGGATTTTTTGGTTC...   _NA_
876   AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTN...   _NA_`

I then extracted the uniques sequences, found there are 53 different types of sequences. Finally I assigned to each unique sequence a character value from `"A"` to `"BA"`.
`UNIQUE <- read.csv("UNIQUE.csv")
UNIQUE
Ind   Seq                             Tipo
1     AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTC...  A
2     AACTTTTAAAAACGGGTTCTTTGGTTC...  B
3     AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTC...  C
10    AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGGTC...  J
30    AACTTTCAACAACGGATTTTTTGGTTC...  AD
53    AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTN...  BA`

What I want is, for every value in `TOTAL$Seq` find a match in `UNIQUE$Seq`. Then assign to `TOTAL$Haplo` a value in `UNIQUE$Haplo` that corresponds to the matched with `UNIQUE$Seq`. How can I do that?

`TOTAL
Ind   Seq                              Tipo
1     AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTC...   A
2     AACTTTTAAAAACGGGTTCTTTGGTTC...   B
3     AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTC...   C
4     AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTC...   C
52    AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGGTC...   J
821   AACTTTCAACAACGGATTTTTTGGTTC...   AD
876   AACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTN...   BA`

Comment: try with `match ` surely it will work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
TOTAL$Seq<-as.character(TOTAL$Seq)
TOTAL<-TOTAL[,1:2]
UNIQUE$Seq<-as.character(UNIQUE$Seq)
left_join(TOTAL, UNIQUE, by="Seq")
```

If you're getting a column called Ind.y, replace `UNIQUE` in the last line with `UNIQUE[,2:3]`

Comment: Tried but dindt work, I posted a new question trying to be more explicative and specific.

Comment: How did it not work? Did you get an error? Was the result not what you were looking for? Can you give a slightly longer sample of your data so we can play around with it?

Comment: For sure I'll post an answer so I can be more explicative. Being brief, `LJ <- left_join(TOTAL, UNIQUE, by="Seq")` prints this **"Warning message:
Column `Seq` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector "** also it creates a df with the columns `LF$Tipo.x` and `LF$Tipo.y`  with _NA_ values.

Comment: Right, so that's because your Seq columns are factor rather than character. I amended my solution to include code that would change them to character instead. Now it should work.

Comment: Also, don't post new questions (or answers) - edit your existing questions to add more information as needed.

Comment: Done it. Not getting the warning message anymother, but still create the two extra columns named `Tipo.x` and `Tipo.y` with _NA_ values.

Comment: Why do you have the Tipo column in TOTAL? Remove it, and your problem should be gone (see amended code in my answer)